# Disabling CSS Wild Card

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS which used to be relevant for my whole page:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;  
}
```

But then I realised I wanted this style to be applied to a specific portion of the page (with class="forms") only as such:

```
div[class="forms"],
div[class="forms"]:after,
div[class="forms"]:before {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;  
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `div.forms` is probably what you're looking for (rather than `div[class="forms"]`).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `.` to indicate class

```
div.forms,
div.forms:after,
div.forms:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesnt seem to work. But then                                                                                                            *,
div.form:after,
div.form:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  
}  Works

Answer (score 0):

Patrick you are writing the wrong css.
To target a specific class (in your case "form") you need to change the css code to

```
div.forms
```

note that "." is a css selector for a class. in your html code you will be using it like

```
<div class="forms"></div>
```

Please read more on css selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: I have done as you instructed but it did not work. After more fiddling with the code, i realised the real problem came about due to the line "box-sizing: border-box;" which still affects other elements not enclosed in the class "forms". How do i go about solving the problem?

Comment: Can you upload the html code also ? It will help to understand the problem :)